# No rule existing for libboost_date_time.a

Tags: makefile

I am trying to compile [OpenBM](https://github.com/cgart/OpenBM) on my x64 Ubuntu box.

```
$ LANG=C make CONF=Release
"make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Release.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/david/Development/OpenBM_git/OpenBM/gateway'
"make"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Release.mk dist/Release/GNU-Linux-x86/gateway
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/david/Development/OpenBM_git/OpenBM/gateway'
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `/usr/lib/libboost_date_time.a', needed by `dist/Release/GNU-Linux-x86/gateway'.  Stop.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/david/Development/OpenBM_git/OpenBM/gateway'
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/david/Development/OpenBM_git/OpenBM/gateway'
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2
```

Please ask me if you need any information in order to help me. Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you do `LANG=C make CONF=release`? By the way, the English version of the error message will not help you that much. It looks like the `boost date-time` library was not properly installed.

Comment: This happens on 2 different boxes, and also on my raspberry.  
I repostet in english now.

Comment: Maybe try `sudo apt-get install libboost-date-time-dev` to install the required boost library

Comment: It seems to be included within libboot-all-dev, so it's already installed :(

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22472238/1380680) looks the same, maybe that helps?